# is there a way to add CSS/JS later using EJS with nodejs/express

Tags: node.js, template-engine, express, ejs

i'm using the EJS template engine with nodejs/express and i'm wondering if it's possible to add another css or js file in e.g the index.ejs (not the layout.ejs)

**layout.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <%- body %>
  </body>
</html>
```

**index.ejs**

```
<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
```

i don't want to add the second css file in every template but only the index.ejs - is there any way i can do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

found a solution here: [Node.js with Express: Importing client-side javascript using script tags in Jade views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605392/node-js-with-express-importing-client-side-javascript-using-script-tags-in-jade)

it's using jade instead of EJS but works all the same.
here are some code-snippets for express 2.4.0.

you have to add the following "helpers" to your app.js

```
app.helpers({
  renderScriptsTags: function (all) {
    if (all != undefined) {
      return all.map(function(script) {
        return '<script src="/javascripts/' + script + '"></script>';
      }).join('\n ');
    }
    else {
      return '';
    }
  }
});

app.dynamicHelpers({
  scripts: function(req, res) {
    return ['jquery-1.5.1.min.js'];
  }
});
```

the **layout.ejs** looks sth like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
      <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
      <%- renderScriptsTags(scripts) %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%- body %>
  </body>
</html>
```

if you don't add any scripts to the scripts-array, only 'jquery-1.5.1.min.js' will be included - if you want to add files to a subpage you can do this like so:

**test.ejs**

```
<% scripts.push('jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js', 'jquery.validate.min.js') %>

<h1><%= title %></h1>
<p>I'm a template with 3 js files in the header</p>
```

that's it.

Comment: If you happen to have expressjs > 3.x.x read my answer below for working code. Credit goes to pkyeck ! :)

Answer (score 11):

As helpers and dynamicHelpers are gone in Express > 3, I rewrote [pkyeck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388026/pkyeck) code so it works in Express 3.

So in app.js have this instead of the helpers / dynamicHelpers. Leave everything else as is.

```
app.locals({
    scripts: [],
  renderScriptsTags: function (all) {
    app.locals.scripts = [];
    if (all != undefined) {
      return all.map(function(script) {
        return '<script src="/javascripts/' + script + '"></script>';
      }).join('\n ');
    }
    else {
      return '';
    }
  },
  getScripts: function(req, res) {
    return scripts;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

---

### In app.js add line:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); // This line.
```

---

### In layout.ejs:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Authentication Example</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css"/>
    <script src="/javascripts/jquery.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <%- body %>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

### In index.ejs or login.ejs:

```
<h1>Login</h1>
<form method="post" action="/login">
  <p>
    <label>Username:</label>
    <input type="text" name="username">
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>Password:</label>
    <input type="text" name="password">
  </p>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
  </p>
</form>
<script src="/javascripts/test.js"></script> <!-- Second Script -->
```

---

### In test.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    try{
        alert("Hi!!!");
    }catch(e)
    {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks @asprotte for providing this for express 4.x. Did you tested this?
 Because it does not appears to be working for me. So I have made some changes to your code here are they:

Put this in app.js file

```
app.locals.scripts = [];
app.locals.addScripts=function (all) {
app.locals.scripts = [];
    if (all != undefined) {
        app.locals.scripts =  all.map(function(script) {
            console.log(script);
            return "<script src='/js/" + script + "'></script>";
        }).join('\n ');
    }

};
app.locals.getScripts = function(req, res) {
    return app.locals.scripts;
};
```

then in template file put (I am using ejs template here) :

```
<% addScripts(['cart.js']) %>
```

Then in the layout file we need these  to append at the bottom of the page get the scripts

```
<%- getScripts() %>
```

I have tested it and its working for me. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for illustrating this option pkyeck!

In express 4.x app.locals is an object. Here's pkyeck's answer rewritten to work in express 4.x:

```js
app.locals.scripts = [];
app.locals.addScripts=function (all) {
    app.locals.scripts = [];
    if (all != undefined) {
        return all.map(function(script) {
            return "<script src='/javascripts/" + script + "'></script>";
        }).join('\n ');
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
};
app.locals.getScripts = function(req, res) {
    return scripts;
};
```