# Add scripts in express-handlebars from view

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I am using Express-Handlebars as my templating engine and I use a layout for all my views. However, I want to be able to add scripts via the view for specific pages. Very much like in this example: [is there a way to add CSS/JS later using EJS with nodejs/express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609238/is-there-a-way-to-add-css-js-later-using-ejs-with-nodejs-express#6622034)

I want to add my scripts after the standard scripts that are used for all pages(bootstrap, jquery). These are placed at  the bottom of body in my layout, like so:

```
<html>
<header>
...
</header>
<body>
...
{{{body}}}

<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How would I go about doing this using Handlebars? Or is my best bet to use EJS? Or can I use both?

Any help is much appreciated,
Freece

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Never mind! I realized that that method would contradict the foundations of Handlebars. Instead I added the following to my controller:

```
var scripts = [{ script: '/js/myTestScript.js' }];
...
res.render('contact', { title: 'Kontakt', scripts: scripts });
```

And in my layout it looks like this:

```
...
<script src="/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
{{#each scripts}}
  <script src="{{script}}"></script>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: I'm trying to do a simila thing but I have some problems. Could you post the entire code?

Comment: Very elegant! Thanks! I am just passing one script per page though so instead of `#each` I simply used `{{ script }}` on my `main.hbs` and passed in `script: <script-path>` through my router.