# how to use app.locals. parameter inside javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json

I am developing a node.js application.  I loaded a JSON file as app.locals.parameter in app.js.
then I am trying to use it in my index.hbs.

Assume:

```
app.locals.componentData = require('./myfile.json');
```

when I used the parameter inside my HTML part as below it is functioning properly.

```
 {{#each componentData.categories}}
        <li id="{{this.categoryName}}" name="{{this.categoryName}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="position: relative; z-index: 10; margin-bottom:3px" draggable="true" role="option" aria-grabbed="false"><div><img src="images/plugin.png" alt="{{this.categoryDescription}}"/>{{this.categoryName}}</div></li>
 {{/each}}
```

but when I am trying to use the parameter in my javascript function it cannot recognize it.

```
function InitComponents() {
         for( var i = 0; i < componentData.categories.length; i++ ){
             alert("in loop!"+i+"-"+componentData.categories[i].categoryName);
              if(componentData.categories[i].categoryName.match(itemId)){
              alert("here:"+componentData.categories[i].parameters.length);
          createParameterList(newID,componentData.categories[i].parameters);
                        }

            }

    }
```

my JSON format is as below:

```
{
    "categoryName": "xyz",
    "categories": [
      {
        "categoryName": "ABC", 
        "parameters": [
          {
            "ParameterID": "ID",
            "ParameterName": "ID",
            "ParameterDefultValue": "",
            "ParameterValue": "",
            "ParameterDescription": "ID Description"
          }]
}]
}
```

may I know why system cannot understand 
 **componentData.categories.length**
 in my script part?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `InitComponents` function doesn't know anything about `app.locals`. `app.locals` variable is recognized inside templates. In order to make your code work you need to pass `app.locals.componentData` as a parameter to `InitComponents` function:

```
function InitComponents(componentData) {
     for( var i = 0; i < componentData.categories.length; i++ ){
         alert("in loop!"+i+"-"+componentData.categories[i].categoryName);
          if(componentData.categories[i].categoryName.match(itemId)){
            alert("here:"+componentData.categories[i].parameters.length);
            createParameterList(newID,componentData.categories[i].parameters);
          }
     }
}
```

Now you can call this function like this

```
InitComponents(app.locals.componentData);
```

and `InitComponents` will now actually know what `componentData` is.
If you use this function inside a middleware you can access `app` via `req.app`:

```
myMiddlewareFunction((req, res, next) => {
    const app = req.app;
    initComponents(app.locals.componentData);
    // some other logic
})
```

Comment: @volodymry: Thanks for your answer. I added changes as you said, but now in my button which called Initial component I received this error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined."  Also, can you explain the last part of your answer, I didnt get it. where I should add it?

Comment: @Amir can you please share the code of the function inside which you call `InitComponents` function?

Comment: @Volodymry: I call it like this: <button onclick="InitComponents()">Initialize Components</button> [previously]  and now => <button onclick="InitComponents(app.locals.componentData)">Initialize Components</button>

Comment: I think, I misunderstood your question. I thought you are trying to use `componentData` inside JS on NodeJS side. But as far as I got it now you are trying to use `componentData` inside a frontend script. If so you need to fetch this JSON file from your server and to assign it to a variable inside your script. Or you can insert a `<script>` tag inside a template with javascript that will assign `componentData` to a global variable.

Comment: can you modify your answer based on your new understanding. because I am new to NodeJS. As I mentioned above I loaded the JSON in app.locals.componentData in app.js; I can use componentData successfully in my HTML part but in script part I dont know how to use it. :(

Comment: @Amir is the HTML you are talking about generated by NodeJS from index.hbs?

Comment: I tried to load my json file inside <script> tag by var jsonData = require('./myfile.json');   but it seems that it is not possible!

Comment: @Amir if you want to download your JSON you need to use [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) - `const  componentData = fetch('public.path.to.your.json').then(response => response.json());`. Also you will need to make this JSON served by your NodeJS application ([how to serve static files in expressjs](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)).

Comment: If you want to include your json inside <script> in hbs template you can try to insert the following - `<script>window.componentData = {{componentData}}</script>` and you should be able to use `window.componentData` in your browser script

Comment: also this answer can help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40386257/add-scripts-in-express-handlebars-from-view

Comment: when I used <script>window.componentData = {{componentData}}</script> I am receiving this error:  Uncaght SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier  
The output is also is like this: <script>window.componentData = [object Object]</script>   any Idea what is going on?

Comment: this answer will help you with this issue - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232574/handlebars-js-parse-object-instead-of-object-object . You will need to use `JSON.parse` in you browser script to covert JSON to a plain object.

Comment: however I would like to suggest you to go with `fetch` approach because it is less hacky