# How do I use connect-assetmanager in my html/ejs template?

Tags: node.js, node.js-connect

I may be completely misunderstanding how to use [connect-assetmanager](https://github.com/mape/connect-assetmanager) for my node project. But I have set up which js files I want to package up into a 'group' - but how do I refer to this group in my ejs/jade template?

Surely I need to somehow 'render' this package in my template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Jade: `script(type='text/javascript', src='/the/groups/route')`

Your asset groups should have a route specified. That regex is used to determine if a request is asking for the that group. If it matches, it should serve the group.

Comment: Yes, but your solution handles the cache busting, which really helps development and eliminates telling people to hard refresh. Taking your solution and combining it with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605392/node-js-with-express-importing-client-side-javascript-using-script-tags-in-jade would be optimal.

Comment: So true - thanks for reminding me why I liked my solution too :-)

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution:

In your server for example, you could set up a dynamic helper like so:

```
app.dynamicHelpers({
  'assetsCacheHashes': function(req, res) { 
    return assetsManagerMiddleware.cacheHashes;
  }
});
```

where assetsManagerMiddleware represents your assetManager.

Then in your ejs template, you can render the generated asset package like so:

```
<script src="/js/<%= assetsCacheHashes.js || 0 %>.js"></script>
```

In your view source - see which path it is choosing and adjust your path accordingly.